# param check for function to use chained method

Tags: javascript

I want to check for the cache param in this option.

So if the param was included and is true then .use would set the no_cache --otherwise not.

```
My.function = function (data, callback, cache) {
return this.client.request("patch", this.uri())
    .use(no_cache)
    .send(data)
    .end(utils.easy(callback));
};
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to send if true isn't sent. Perhaps undefined? You can use a ternary operation

```
My.function = function (data, callback, cache) {
 return this.client.request("patch", this.uri())
 .use(cache === true ? no_cache : undefined)
 .send(data)
 .end(utils.easy(callback));
};
```